# Шифрование ссылок для скачивания

Tags: файлы, php, ссылки, шифрование

Вопрос довольно популярный, объясните пожалуйста каким образом можно наиболее адекватно шифровать ссылки для скачивания. То есть пользователь вошел -> для него генерируется ссылка, допустим на `zip` архив, ну и удаляется после скачки. Ни когда таким не занимался, стало интересно.

Comment: мне также надо скрыть ссылка на лог файлы например, как можно реализовать такой метод с помощью php 

Comment: логи обычно хранят в директории которая находится выше директории доступной из интернет или в директорию с логами добавляют файл .htaccess (в случае если сервер Apache) в который прописывают - deny from all

Comment: я знаю, что они там хранятся, но это логи apache, а мне нужны мои логи веб сайта, которые сохраняет php в log папку указанную мной. Да я знаю, что нужно положить файл .htaccess с Deny from All. Мне нужно было сделать так, чтобы небыло прямой ссылки на файл и директорию, но я уже частично решил ее. через header() octek stream точно не помню как называется

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно пользоваться средствами веб сервера:

- модуль [SecureLink](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSecureLinkModule) для nginx (вовсю использую);
- и, кажется, [mod-auth-token](https://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-token/) для Apache.

**Upd.** Можно написать и свою реализацию на том же php, но есть очевидный минус: перформанс. Чтобы не показывать истинный адрес файла, придётся пропускать его контент сквозь работающий php скрипт в течение всего времени скачивания. Т.е. в памяти будет висеть по тяжеленному процессу php на каждую сессию скачивания. А веб сервер делает то же самое, легко и изящно.

А, ещё можно создавать временную копию ценного файла, или, лучше, [линк на него](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php), со странным именем-абракадаброй, и стирать через опр. время.

Comment: хорошее решение, но интересует решения без дополнительных модулей.

Comment: Обновил ответ: про минусы реализации на php и идея со временными копиями/линками.

Comment: Все бы хорошо, но ведь не предугадаешь, когда пользователь скачает файл, во всяком случае модуль SecureLink для nginx (вовсю использую);, меня вполне устроил.

Comment: с линком хорошее решение. Суть я думаю понял правильно )

А еще можно отслеживать кто запрашивает этот линк, и давать его только первому IP адресу (ну или первым 5), остальным блокировать доступ. И удалить его через пару дней (за это врем должны уж скачать)

Comment: @IVsevolod как вы определите скачал человек файл или нет? Вполне может быть что связь прервется, а линк уже недоступен.

Сейчас занимаюсь похожей задачей, линк валидный сутки, человеку дается линк с хешем, по нему определяется через БД валидность и отдается. В положительном случае устанавливается соответствующий заголовок header ... и скидывается содержимое файла, у пользователя появляется окошко которое предлагает скачать этот файл, все.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут человек приводит свой готовый класс для таких целей: [Временная ссылка для скачивания файла](http://php.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=790).

Comment: довольно старенький класс, хотелось бы увидеть что понове

Answer (score 2):

С помощью php придумываем ссылку и с помощью mod_rewrite подсовываем файл.

Например такой .htaccess где index.php обрабатывает все запросы:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил так задачу.

Зделал файл скачивания назовем его download.php

При заходе участника (За регестрированного пользователя) на сайт даем ему случайно сгенерированный ключ, который активен пока пользователь на сайте ?key=KJSJH#*&*&#EGJHJ к нему прикручиваем имя файла и директорию пользователя в которой находится файл. Отдаем все это через Header() application/octet-stream Ключ можно проверять через сессию например $_SESSION['confirm_download_key'];

незнаю насколько эффективно, но пока работает.

Comment: Пользователь эту ссылку тут же дает друзьям, и файл скачивают еще 50 человек. А по окончании сессии (кстати, сколько она живет?), эти созданные файл+директория каким образом удаляются?

Comment: для каждого пользователя который входит генерируется собственный ключ который загоняется в переменную сессии $_SESSION['confirm_download_key']; а про папки пока незнаю у меня передается папка пользователя в которой хранится файл и естественно она не корневая. в скрипте у меня для каждой папки определенна переменная например $_GET['downloadlog']  Значит папку logs. конечно варваский способ и реально не доработанный, но сейчас время нету вообще.

Comment: Переменные сессии могут определится для каждого пользователя отдельно или я не прав? под корректируйте меня